# ¿Cuál es el significado de this.el? ¿Cómo accedo a los atributos en funciones prototipadas de Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Me he topado con **`this.el`** dentro de una función constructora llamada gnMenu y la verdad no entiendo su significado y **no sé por qué lo utilizan junto a querySelector dentro del método _init del prototipo**.

Aquí dejo una parte del codigo donde vi el `this.el`

```js
(function (window) {

  'use strict';

  function gnMenu (el, options) {
    this.el = el;
    this._init();
  }

  gnMenu.prototype = {
    _init: function () {
      this.trigger    = this.el.querySelector('gn-menu-item'); 
      this.menu       = this.el.querySelector('gn-submenu');  
      this.isMenuOpen = false;
      var self         = this;
    }

  };

  window.gnMenu = gnMenu;

})(window);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` funciona un poco diferente en JavaScript respecto a otros lenguajes.

En el contexto en el que aparece dentro de tu código, `this.el` crea un atributo (el equivalente a un atributo en lenguajes orientados a objetos) llamado `el` y lo inicializa con el parámetro `el` que se le pasa a la función `gnMenu`, con la asignación **`this.el = el`.** **Para no confundir el atributo con el parámetro, se utiliza `this` para referirse al primero.**

Ocurre un poco lo mismo en la función prototipada `_init`. Ésta es llamada con `this._init()`, por lo que la linea de ejecución pasa a esta función. Desde ahí se crean nuevos atributos (`trigger`, `menu`, `isMenuOpen` y `self`) y los dos primeros se inicializan según el valor del atributo anteriormente inicializado con el parámetro que le pasas a la función (`el`). Para acceder correctamente a él (al atributo), y como éste ya existe, hay que escribir **`this.el`** y luego ejecutar su `querySelector()`, quedando al final almacenado el valor de `this.el.querySelector('gn-menu-item');` en `trigger`.

> Caso especial es el atributo `self`, que guarda una copia del contexto donde reside él mismo (`this`), manteniendo así una referencia al `this` original para esta "clase", lo cual resulta muy útil para luego acceder al contexto adecuado cuando se llaman a métodos dentro de otras *funciones/bucles_con_each/cosas_extrañas_de_JS*. Tienes más info sobre esto [aqui](http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations)

Comment: Muchas gracias Mik por responder, tengo una duda si paso como parametro a la funcion por ejemplo un elemento : var menu = new gnMenu('aside') el querySelector buscara dentro de ese elemento? es que no veo el sentido de colocar el querySelector al this.el no seria mejor referenciar directamente el elemento document.querySelector(); o esto se hace por cuestiones de rendimiento? , **a la hora de pasar un parametro a la instancia de gnMenu me aparece en consola que this.el.querySelector no es una funcion**

Comment: Como dices, buscar en `document` toma mucho más tiempo que solo buscar en `el` (lease como element), además que posiblemente necesites aplicar más de uno, en fin.  El hecho de que te marca el tipico **is not a function** es porque el elemento que pasas no es uno valido, tienes que recogerlo con _querySelector()_ , por ejemplo ```new gnMenu(document.querySelector('menu'))```

Comment: Coincido con elporfirio ;) Es mucho más eficiente buscar en un elemento directamente, que no en el DOM entero.

Por otro lado, querySelector es una función base que tienen todos los elementos del DOM, así que te debería funcionar (salvo que haya problemas con el nombre, en plan escapar caracteres o algo así).
Puedes revisar la documentación de MDN referente a esto aqui -> https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector